# ¿Se puede utilizar un texto introducido en un <input> de HTML en otro campo?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una consulta un poco rara. 
Mi idea es implementar una API a mi HTML. Sucede que el comando de la API se ejecuta si el usuario entra al link. El problema es el siguiente: Para que el link funcione, este pide ciertos parametros. Los cuales por ejemplo son: "d0" y "d1". ¿A que me refiero con parametros? Básicamente el nombre de las variables o de los `<input>`. El link reconoce estos y entonces la API funciona. Queria preguntar si es posible "extraer" un valor almacenado dentro de una variable como en Java para luego utilizarlo de la siguiente forma: `<form action="https://www.google.com + nombre + apellido"`.
Donde "nombre" y "apellido" son el id del `<input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello usa JavaScript

```
 <script>
 document.getElementById("Id del botón"). addEventListener ("click", function(){
       valor = document.getElementById("Id del input").value;
       window.open("url" + valor);
 });
 </script>
```

Lo que haces con eso es que cuando le des clic al botón con el Id que le pasas, se ejecuten la función esa que obtiene el input con el segundo getElementById() a partir del Id determinado y guarda su valor en la variable valor.
Finalmente se ejecuta window.open() con el link que le asignen y se concatenar con la variable que posee el valor obtenido del input.
Añade otros inputs y repite la línea de código

```
 valor = document.getElementById("Id del input").value
```

por cada uno con variable e Id diferentes. Por último tendrás que editar las variables y las cadenas de texto que se concatenaran en

```
 window.open("url" + valor);
```

Un último detalle, lo mejor es ubicar el script al final del body, así ya estará completamente cargado y no habrá errores de que algo no exista por querer acceder a algo que no existe.

Comment: Lo tienes mal escrito aquí: `ID` la d es minúscula

Comment: Solo era a modo de ejemplo, aún así sugieres que lo corrija?

Comment: Claro que sí pues si no alguien más que lo usé se encontrará Con dicho fallo. Saludos

Comment: Ah ya entendí a lo que te refieres, en el código. Gracias.

Comment: Acabo de aplicar la correcion de las D